# how to do 'select in' operation in sqlobject

Tags: python, sql, sqlobject

I want write a SQL statement like this:

```
select * from 'table' t where t.id in (1,2,4)
```

But I don't how to using SQLObject's grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
from sqlobject.sqlbuilder import IN
TableClass.select(IN(TableClass.q.id, [1, 2, 4]))
```

This will return a [SelectResults](http://www.sqlobject.org/SelectResults.html) object instance. Therefore to get the list of instances you have to:

```
resultList = list(TableClass.select(IN(TableClass.q.id, [1, 2, 4])))
```

Comment: Great, it's ok now, thanks very much.  Firstly i using select(In(id,[1,2,3,4])) ,there always  return None to me .